# SQL -- WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING query

Tags: sql, group-by, language-agnostic

A table `grade` looks like this

| course | year | pass |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English | 2019 | Yes |
| Math | 2020 | Yes |
| Math | 2020 | No |
| Chemistry | 2021 | No |

It shows the grade of a student for all courses in each of the calendar year. A course can be taken multiple times every year. The datatype of pass is bool. Now I want to know all the courses which get passed at least one time in each of the year 2020 and 2021.

My query is

```sql
SELECT course 
FROM grade
WHERE year IN (2020, 2021)
GROUP BY course, year
HAVING SUM(pass) > 0;
```

But it shows the courses satisfy either year 2020 or 2021. How to only show the courses satisfy both year 2020 and 2021?

Comment: Are you using mysql, sql server or postgresql? You tagged all of them.

Comment: I don't think it matters, or you can view it as pseudo sql.

Comment: It certainly does matter. This question is easily answered with conditional aggregation, but Postgres and others support `FILTER`, SQL Server does not. SQL Server also doesn't support `bool` columns, only `bit`

Answer (score 1):

This query could work

```
SELECT course 
FROM grade
WHERE year IN (2020, 2021)
AND pass = 'yes'
GROUP BY course
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all the corner cases will be covered with this query, but you could try it out;

```
SELECT course FROM grade WHERE pass='yes' and (year=2021 or year=2020);
```

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.

Comment: I will implement this ASAP. Thank you for your suggestion @Tyler2P.

Answer (score 0):

In fairly generic SQL, you can use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT course 
FROM grade
WHERE year IN (2020, 2021)
AND pass = 'yes'
GROUP BY course
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 2020 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 2021 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Some RDBMSs support the `FILTER` syntax, which makes things clearer

```sql
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE year = 2020) > 0
   AND COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE year = 2021) > 0
```

Note also that not every RDBMS supports `bool` columns, nor do all the ones that do recognize `yes` as `true`